# Python Substituiting a float only giving whole number

Tags: python, variables, floating-point, arguments

I'm reading into a csv file an extracting a piece of data with the line:

```
x = float(node[1])
```

when I print(x), I get the correct value or the exact value found in the cell. e.g 153.018848

But when I try to pass x as variable in the following:

```
print('<node version="0" lon="%d">' %(x))
```

the output will be `<node version="0" lon="153">` . Of course I want the value 153.018848.

What have I overlooked?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've overlooked the fact that [`%d` is for integers](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). Try `%f` instead.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there was a difference. I always thought it was some arbitrary letter. Anyways, it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace your %d with %f, problem solved ;)

See: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html

For bonus points, are you aware you can put together long format strings that are still readable using dictionaries? You can read more about it, but the !r option I have used with call the **repr**() function on the variable, so you know what is inserted will be exactly what you've seen printed in your debugging:

```
string = """<tagname id=%{idval!r} type=%{tagtype!r} foo=%{bar!r}"""
print string.format( **{'idval':var1, 'tagtype':var2, 'bar':var3})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong format flag. %d is for integers, use %f for floats.